# Autogenerate array values with a loop?

Tags: php

I know this doesn't work but is there any way of autogenerating values? It can be pretty tedious to put so many values in specially if it's 50 or maybe 100 numbers...

Here's the code so you get my idea:

```
for ($num = 1; $num <= 20; $num++){
    $arr = array($num);
    echo $arr[2];
};
```

Solved: It was the range() and arrayfill(). :)

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t get your idea. Can you create a more explicit example (preferably with the expected output)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`range()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function.

```
>> $a = range(1, 10);
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 6,
  6 => 7,
  7 => 8,
  8 => 9,
  9 => 10,
)
>>
```

Or maybe [`array_fill()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the rand() function? That surely exist ;)

[PHP Rand Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)